# Updating FieldName "Editor" to be same as "Created By" dynamic content using JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, json

I am wracking my brain to find a way within SharePoint to overwrite the `Modified By` column value of an item with the value within the `Created By` column.

I have scoured the internet and have found CSOM examples here on SE, but they do not answer my specific dilemma, as I am attempting to do this specifically through JSON Composers and an Sending an HTTP request to SharePoint using the output of those JSON Composers.

As a reference, I am using [this article](http://johnliu.net/blog/2019/2/flowninja-hack-78-modifying-modified-by-and-modified-time-with-microsoft-flow) to give me the biggest bulk of work, and I have the JSON Formatted correctly, but it still will not update the `Modified By` parameter of a file.  I have disabled all other flows which may modify the file to ensure this change should be done.

My current JSON input from the HTTP Request looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "FieldName": "Editor",
    "FieldValue": "[{\"Key\":\"i:0#.f|membership|SomeEmail@onmicrosoft.com\"}]"
  },
  {
    "FieldName": "Title",
    "FieldValue": "SomeTitleOfFileSinceTitlesAreNotPrePopulatedinSharePoint.pdf"
  }
]
```

I know my JSON works appropriately for the Title field, as the Title field updates appropriately, AND, my version of the file does not increment up so I know the final line is appropriately working as well!  I feel like I'm missing something really really simple. . .

I've also tried using the `odata` (`"Created By"`) Dynamic Content values pulled directly from the body of the file, as well as the (`"Created by Display Name"`) Dynamic Content value.  I am populating the `"i:0#.f. . .` Key using (`"Created by Claims"`) Dynamic Content value as well.  Below are screenshots of my flow:

[image: Compose JSON Action Examples]

[image: Send an HTTP request to SharePoint example]

I am baffled by this and am seriously hoping I'm forgetting something or using "" when I should be using '' etc.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh for updating my tags!  I did not realize there were tags for flow and power-automate!  It's cool to see everyone has thought about just about everything!

Comment: For others who stumble upon this - I believe the original flow I had produced _might_ have worked, but the 2 answers below **definitely** work.  There is one caveat however, you (as the developer of the Flow) must have `Full Control` permissions for the Library/List you are trying to work in for these to stick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the exact same thing before in one of my flows where I didn't want to change the "Modified By" field with the name of flow owner/connection.

Below is my flow configuration which copies the "Created By" in "Modified By" column:

[image]

Here I have added `Created by Claims` directly in the `Compose` action. It is working fine for me. So, no need to convert it using `string()` function.

Comment: Using this method, I am able to see the file has a new modified date, but the `Modified By` value of the file(s) do not change!

Comment: Using this flow configuration, "Modified By" should be equal to "Created By". Is the same behavior you observe at your end?

Comment: No - it does not update the `Modified By` value to equal the `Created By` value.  Do I need to have specific rights in order for this to work, or do I need to be a special Admin of some kind?

Comment: I think Edit/Full control permissions on list and Read permissions on site is enough for this.

Comment: Ok.  I am investigating to see what my permissions are.  I know I can edit and delete files, but I cannot create a flow which monitors the deletion of a file because I am not a "Site Collection Admin" user - hopefully this is not a necessary role to perform what I am attempting.

Comment: So - to confirm, this WILL work, BUT, I have to have "Full Control" permissions on the library/list to get it to work.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have done some test and the key shall be on the claims. You will need to first convert it to string and then use it in the compose action. It works in my end on updating the modified by field with another custom person field. Have a try on this. Other steps are exactly same with the blog your provide.
[image]

Comment: When I use your method, I do not get a change in the `Modified By` column, and there is no evidence the file(s) are modified.

Comment: I have tried to +1 your answer as well as the other user's but I do not have enough rep to get them to stick - thank you for your time answering my question.  Once I determined I needed Full Control Permissions, your method also worked in making the `Modified By` value change to the `Created By` value!  I chose the other answer though because it took fewer `Compose` operations to do the same thing.  Thanks for your time!